# Eclipse AndroidManifest.xml format

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, formatting

When I format the xml using Ctrl+Shift+F the result is being like that:

[image: This is the result of Ctrl+Shift+F]

But It would be nice if something can make xml like that:

[image: But I want to have this]

Is there any way to format the formatting on eclipse?

Comment: [THIS](http://eclipsetidy.sourceforge.net/) could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For XML you should go Window->Preferences->HTML Tidy-> XML and select "Input XML" 
[image]

If you like to see every attribute in separate line like me, you should check Wrap attribute values and Indent attributes checkboxes

[image: If you like to see every attribute in separate line like me, you should check Wrap attribute values and Indent attributes checkboxes]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need that plug-in! 
To have all the attributes on their own lines, go to: Window→Preferences→XML→XML Files→Editor and check *Split multiple attributes each on a new line*.

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to auto-format.